# Posting values of repeated table rows

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, http-post

I have the following table:

[image: My table figure]

The table resulted from this code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>        
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="1 in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
            <td>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" size="40" /></td>
            <td>Amount: <input type="text" ng-model="amount"/></td>
            <td>Date: <input type="date" ng-model="date"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<center><button>Send</button></center>
```

How I can post the values of these rows?

Comment: Maybe posting an array? Add `name='table1[]'` to your input tag. everything with this name will be put into an array and sent to the server.

Comment: thanks dear, things are going well now, really thanks @Amous

Comment: I posted an answer with an example, hopefully it helps! If it does maybe accept it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting the information as an array should help. Change your `tbody` to something like this

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="1 in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
    <td>Name: <input name="table[]" type="text" ng-model="name" size="40" /></td>
    <td>Amount: <input name="table[]" type="text" ng-model="amount"/></td>   
    <td>Date: <input name="table[]" type="date" ng-model="date"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

and retrieve the `table` using `$_POST['table']` this will give you something like:

```
array (
      0 => 'John'
      1 => '90'
      2 => 'june'
)
```